# Can't enable NFS on two-node Ansible provisioned GlusterFS cluster

Tags: nfs, ansible, glusterfs, ansible-playbook

I have two nodes (running [Armbian](https://armbian.com/) Bionic, based on Ubuntu 18.04) set up to create a distributed Gluster storage, provisioned via Ansible.

I think the relevant part of the Ansible playbook is this:

```
    - name: Configure gluster volume
      gluster_volume:
        state: present
        name: "{{ gluster_volume_name }}"
        brick: "{{ gluster_brick_dir }}"
        cluster: "{{ groups.glustergroup | join(',') }}"
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        force: yes
      run_once: true
```

Where `glustergroup` is the list of the two nodes in my Ansible inventory file.

On both nodes, when I run `gluster volume info` I see that the volume was created successfully, and it can be mounted via `mount -t glusterfs`. Here's the output of `gluster volume info`:

```
Volume Name: [my volume name]
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: edbc9b23-6252-4725-9652-e46c280dae2b
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: [node 1]:/bricks/brick0
Brick2: [node 2]:/bricks/brick0
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
```

I noticed that `nfs.disable: on`, but I want my clients to mount the volume via NFS. So, I ran `gluster volume set [my volume name] nfs.disable off`, then rebooted the nodes for good measure.

Now, I can see this from `gluster volume status`:

```
Status of volume: [my volume name]
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick [node 1]:/bricks/brick0            49152     0          Y       2338 
Brick [node 2]:/bricks/brick0              49152     0          Y       1526 
NFS Server on localhost                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A  
NFS Server on [node 2]                     N/A       N/A        N       N/A
```

Notice that the `NFS Server`s are still not online in either node.

What else do I need to do to turn on NFS support, so that clients can mount this volume via `/etc/fstab`? *Is there anything I can/should modify in the Ansible playbook to enable this*? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Gluster NFS server is [deprecated](https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs-specs/blob/master/done/GlusterFS%203.8/gluster-nfs-off.md). See [Configuring NFS-Ganesha over GlusterFS](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/NFS-Ganesha%20GlusterFS%20Integration/).There is no NFS-Ganesha module for Ansible AFAIK.

Ubuntu 18.04 [GlusterFS + NFS-Ganesha](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=glusterfs&f=8) seems to be prety strightforward.